# Retrieve the maximum number for each group of records oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I failed to write SQL code to retrieve maximum number in order_number column.
notice that visit_number is group contain more than one record and i want the maximum value of order_number column.

```
visit_number , Order_number , NAME
111          ,     1        , 001
111          ,     2        , 001
111          ,     3        , 001
222          ,     1        , 252
222          ,     2        , 252 
003          ,     1        , 121
003          ,     2        , 121
```

I want the result to be like below matrix:

```
111          ,     3        , 001
222          ,     2        , 252 
003          ,     2        , 121
```

this is my query

```
SELECT VISIT_NUMBER , MAX(ORDER_NUMBER) , NAME
from table
group by ( visit_number , name )
```

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: Does a visit_number always have the same name value?

Comment: Doesn't that query return what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` and the `MAX` function.

```
SELECT visit_number, MAX(Order_number), NAME
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY visit_number, NAME
```

Comment: if the name column changeable does that effect?

Comment: @Nawaf, update your sample data with different names, and also adjust the expected result!

Comment: this query not works it is return the same value either group by function is written or not.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table with a sub-query that returns each visit_number together with its max order_number:

```
SELECT distinct t1.*
FROM tablename t1
  JOIN (select visit_number, MAX(Order_number) as max_Order_number
        from tablename group by visit_number) as t2
  ON t1.visit_number = t2.visit_number and t1.Order_number = t2.max_Order_number
```

(Will return all rows if several different Names for a maximum order number.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select VISIT_NUMBER, ORDER_NUMBER, NAME
from (
select VISIT_NUMBER, ORDER_NUMBER, NAME, row_number() over(partition by VISIT_NUMBER order by ORDER_NUMBER desc) as ORDER_DESC
from TABLE
)
where ORDER_DESC = 1
```

This will return the max for each VISIT_NUMBER, even if the NAME changes